# Excel functions numeric code

Tags: excel, function, numeric

I was wondering if there is a way to export a worksheet from Adobe Flex to Excel on a different language. For example, what if I export it using the functions in english, but somebody with a portuguese version of excel opens it? Are they gonne be able to read normally? If not, is there any reference of the numeric codification for functions? I know that Excel actually use numeric values of functions instead of searching for the name...

Comment: what have you found / tried already?